# How to match peptide sequence from two different condition

Tags: proteomics

I have to peptide output sample output i would give here ..

Sample A

```
dput(head(B5_ILS_Mus_PeptideSummary))
structure(list(N = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Unused = c(47.67, 47.67, 
47.67, 47.67, 47.67, 47.67), Total = c(47.67, 47.67, 47.67, 47.67, 
47.67, 47.67), `%Cov` = c(98.0000019073486, 98.0000019073486, 
98.0000019073486, 98.0000019073486, 98.0000019073486, 98.0000019073486
), `%Cov(50)` = c(86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 
86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115), `%Cov(95)` = c(86.0000014305115, 
86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 
86.0000014305115), Accessions = c("sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", "sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", 
"sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", "sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", "sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", 
"sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE"), Names = c("Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1"
), Used = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Annotation = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Contrib = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Conf = c(99.0000009536743, 
58.2899987697601, 97.5199997425079, 99.0000009536743, 98.9300012588501, 
73.7299978733063), Sequence = c("EKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", "KKTETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", 
"KNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", "KTETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", "LKKTETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", 
"PLPSKETIEQEKQAGES"), Modifications = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), 
    ProteinModifications = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
    NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Cleavages = c(NA, 
    NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dMass = c(-0.0625222995877266, 0.180465996265411, 
    -0.00865099020302296, -0.0651467964053154, -0.107698999345303, 
    -0.0186963994055986), `Obs MW` = c(2241.05004882813, 2956.67944335938, 
    2112.06127929688, 2828.3388671875, 3069.47534179688, 1869.91320800781
    ), `Obs m/z` = c(748.0239, 740.1771, 529.0226, 708.092, 768.3761, 
    624.3117), `Theor MW` = c(2241.11254882813, 2956.4990234375, 
    2112.06982421875, 2828.40405273438, 3069.5830078125, 1869.93200683594
    ), `Theor m/z` = c(748.044738769531, 740.132019042969, 529.024719238281, 
    708.108276367188, 768.403015136719, 624.317932128906), `Theor z` = c(3, 
    4, 4, 4, 4, 3), Sc = c(15, 8, 11, 21, 12, 10), Spectrum = c("1.1.1.372.12", 
    "1.1.1.339.6", "1.1.1.358.3", "1.1.1.355.16", "1.1.1.346.14", 
    "1.1.1.384.8"), `Acq Time` = c(4.2116, 3.539133, 3.91795, 
    3.867617, 3.68345, 4.45125), `Intensity (Peptide)` = c(3775.35, 
    110.58, 4374.93, 7285.52, 3073.51, 5776.43), PrecursorIntensityAcquisition = c(3626.33, 
    37.12, 4301.05, 7124.23, 2706.13, 5533.12), `Apex Time (Peptide)` = c(4.2, 
    3.59, 3.91, 3.85, 3.67, 4.44), `Elution Peak Width (Peptide)` = c(0.1, 
    0.06, 0.08, 0.1, 0.08, 0.08), MS2Counts = c(3077.868, 477.5326, 
    2262.827, 4694.357, 1759.267, 2618.842)), row.names = c(NA, 
-6L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Sample B

```
dput(head(B6_ILS_mus_PeptideSummary))
structure(list(N = c(1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1), Unused = c(82.41, 82.41, 
82.41, 82.41, 82.41, 82.41), Total = c(82.41, 82.41, 82.41, 82.41, 
82.41, 82.41), `%Cov` = c(100, 100, 100, 100, 100, 100), `%Cov(50)` = c(87.9999995231628, 
87.9999995231628, 87.9999995231628, 87.9999995231628, 87.9999995231628, 
87.9999995231628), `%Cov(95)` = c(86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 
86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115, 86.0000014305115
), Accessions = c("sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", "sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", 
"sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", "sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", "sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE", 
"sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE"), Names = c("Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1", 
"Thymosin beta-4 OS=Mus musculus OX=10090 GN=Tmsb4x PE=1 SV=1"
), Used = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), Annotation = c(NA, NA, NA, 
NA, NA, NA), Contrib = c(2, 2, 2, 2, 2, 2), Conf = c(99.0000009536743, 
99.0000009536743, 99.0000009536743, 99.0000009536743, 94.4599986076355, 
99.0000009536743), Sequence = c("DKPDMAEIEKFDKSKLK", "EKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", 
"ETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", "IEKFDKSKLKKTETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", 
"KKTETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES", "KNPLPSKETIEQEK"), Modifications = c(NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_
), ProteinModifications = c(NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_, 
NA_character_, NA_character_, NA_character_), Cleavages = c(NA, 
NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), dMass = c(0.0129736997187138, -0.0542825013399124, 
-0.0299271997064352, -0.107947997748852, -0.0191929005086422, 
-0.0046052997931838), `Obs MW` = c(2021.06335449219, 2241.05834960938, 
2599.2314453125, 4045.01391601563, 2956.47973632813, 1639.87341308594
), `Obs m/z` = c(506.2731, 748.0267, 650.8151, 810.0101, 592.3032, 
547.6318), `Theor MW` = c(2021.05029296875, 2241.11254882813, 
2599.26123046875, 4045.12182617188, 2956.4990234375, 1639.87805175781
), `Theor m/z` = c(506.269866943359, 748.044738769531, 650.822631835938, 
810.031677246094, 592.307067871094, 547.63330078125), `Theor z` = c(4, 
3, 4, 5, 5, 3), Sc = c(11, 12, 12, 26, 10, 10), Spectrum = c("1.1.1.858.2", 
"1.1.1.621.5", "1.1.1.640.9", "1.1.1.643.4", "1.1.1.597.3", "1.1.1.604.4"
), `Acq Time` = c(8.74735, 4.069217, 4.43505, 4.4987, 3.615083, 
3.7369), `Intensity (Peptide)` = c(1798.16, 2856.36, 1278.57, 
5833.81, 758.71, 599.21), PrecursorIntensityAcquisition = c(1603.78, 
443.55, 1104.72, 5265.07, 484.03, 423.02), `Apex Time (Peptide)` = c(8.72, 
4.19, 4.39, 4.45, 3.55, 3.78), `Elution Peak Width (Peptide)` = c(0.14, 
0.12, 0.12, 0.37, 0.1, 0.08), MS2Counts = c(456.3906, 313.663, 
712.3438, 2748.186, 351.0362, 228.9387)), row.names = c(NA, -6L
), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

Unlike genes expression where it can be intersected since i know the gene name or ensemble ID are consistent.

Here My objective is how many of the sequence are common or unique to these two condition.

In the **accession** column many ID are same but the differences are in the sequence column.

Is there any programmatic way of finding the elements that are common or different in both the conditions

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`merge(a, b, by = "Sequence")` would "merge" the two tables (as the name suggests) based on the `Sequence` column. The caveat is that sequences have to be exactly the same to be considered "common to both samples", so even 1 aa difference would be missed.

Simplified output:

```
1       EKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES   1    47.67   47.67     98         86         86 sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE
2 KKTETQEKNPLPSKETIEQEKQAGES   1    47.67   47.67     98         86         86 sp|P20065|TYB4_MOUSE
```